# importing Chinese characters

Tags: magento-1, import

I'm having a problem in importing for Magento. I have 5 different stores, chinese, english, french, español and german. Everything is working out fine but when I look at the chinese store, the product appears to be imported but the info isn't. Its counterparts shows the info in their correctly(in their own languages) except for the chinese store. When checking of the import file, it goes on smoothly, but after importing, it seems that the chinese characters were not imported...

Comment: How are you doing the import?

Comment: csv file. the csv file contains the product the it's attributes in all stores... you can see it here: http://goo.gl/DJbI1

Comment: try saving the CSV file with utf-8 encoding in a text editor that supports this then re-import

Comment: already did... since excel can't handle encoding when converting to csv, i used openoffice, also notepad++

Comment: the commas and the quotes seem a bit funny around the Chinese characters, like Word formatting - did you check that out?

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/file/zOKLy1KJ/import.html here is the original file

Comment: Did you find a solution? What was the problem? Please add an answer and let us know. - And earn 15 reputation by answering your own question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your import file is encoded as UTF8 or another version that supports Chinese characters.  You can switch the encoding of a file in many different text editors.

Comment: already did that matt, check my comment above...